# Can't import ES6 react module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

## Repro

https://github.com/jim-king-2000/nextbugrepro

## Detail

I create a very simple react component.

```
const My = () => (<div>ABC</div>);
export default My;
```

It is in a standalone library project(https://github.com/jim-king-2000/react-module).

Now I use the component in another project.

```
// index.js
import { My } from 'react-module';


// package.json
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react-module": "git+https://github.com/jim-king-2000/react-module.git"
}
```

Then, node.js complains:

```
error  in ./node_modules/react-module/components/My.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.


const My = () => (<div>ABC</div>);
export default My;
./node_modules/react-module/index.js 1:0-32 1:0-32
@ ./pages/index.js
@ multi ./pages/index.js
```

## Question

How to build a ES6 react npm library?

Comment: This is a Webpack message. Where is the Webpack config?

Comment: I use next.js, which uses webpack implicitly.

Comment: remove the curly braces from the import statement

Comment: I didn't use My.js directly. There is an index.js which reexports "My" like this "export * from './components/My';". So, the curly braces are OK. You could check the repro out to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup babel compile, in order to compile jsx, which seems to be missing in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation for several hours, I find that the library has to be transpiled to ES5. I hope we could use ES6 npm modules in the future.